# Why does the default Ember .watchmanconfig not ignore node_modules?

Tags: ember.js, watchman

A lot of people have watchman issues (limits exceeded, etc.), and I looked through the default `.watchmanconfig` in Ember.

It looks like this:

```
{
  "ignore_dirs": ["tmp", "dist"]
}
```

It certainly makes sense to watch those two folders, but I'm wondering: why not also ignore `node_modules`? Are there any real disadvantages to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...why not also ignore node_modules?

Don't you want it to reload your app if you install/upgrade a node module?

> If all you need is auto-reload on *your code changes*, I'm assuming one could ignore the `tests` folder too.

Sure, but when you run Ember in test mode, don't you want it to rerun your tests when they change?

Comment: Updating/upgrading node modules doesn't happen that often. So, should I feel free to just ignore it if it would help otherwise?

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal Well, perhaps not in your case. Anyway, watching an additional directory with watchman doesn't have much of an additional cost, if any, especially if it's not changing often. You should ignore directories based on the behavior you want. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: `inotify limit too low`, for example. There are various other solutions, and while looking into it I was just curious if there was any real point to watching node_modules at all.

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal Well, you can raise the limit, for one. If you don't want to do that, the alternative is excluding node_modules and manually restarting your app when you do `yarn upgrade` or `ember install` or what have you.